# Check if one java condition is subset of another condition

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a use case where I have to check if one condition is subset of another condition. Meaning, the result set that satisfies condition 2 will be the subset of result  set that satisfies condition 1.

I was checking and intellij does figures it out during code inspection

```
if (x < 7 && x > 1) {
      return true;
} else if (x > 3 && x <6) {
      return false;
}
```

Here during code inspection it does highlights that result of second condition is always false.

So, How it is implemented?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say something more like "missing return statement"?

Answer (score 1):

This range:

```
(x > 3 && x <6)
```

is a subrange of:

```
(x < 7 && x > 1)
```

so if the condition `(x < 7 && x > 1)`

1. is `true` then this condition `(x > 3 && x <6)` will not be reached
2. is `false` then this condition `(x > 3 && x <6)` is also `false`
   So the meaning of code inspection is:
   **if** `(x > 3 && x <6)` is reached then it is always **false**.

The right way to implement your logic should be to check first the subrange:

```
if (x > 3 && x <6) {
    return false;
} else if (x > 1 && x < 7) {
    return true;
} else {
    return ....;
}
```

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I understand that why it is false, what I want to know if I have to implement it myself than how can I do it. Like, I have given two conditions how can I implement to figure out that output of second condition will always be false in favor of first one

Comment: @NitinAgrawal That largely depends on what sorts of predicates you're dealing with. If it's just `x < A && x > B` expressions then it's pretty easy, and this answer should cover you. But the problem, in general, is non-computable.